# I have an optional value that is assigned a value, printed succesfully, but when i check it it's nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, option-type

[image]

The optional Bool paid is nil.
It gets assigned a value.
The value is printed.
Next line of code i have an else if.
The value is nil.
Question: how and why?

Comment: Copy/paste code, it's better. WHat's the output of the logs? If you have multiple document, it'd be the last value only (since it's override)?

Comment: As mentioned already, you need to post your code, not an image. That being said, it looks to me like you're not printing `paid`, you're printing `dict["paid"]`.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: *The optional Bool paid is nil. It gets assigned a value* - no, it doesn't. You would need a nil coalescing operator for that - `paid = dict["paid"] as? Bool ?? true`. However since that's in a loop it will be assigned over and over by the loop and will always be whatever the last iteration of the loop sets it to. Also force-unwrapping an optional is often unwise, so this `paid!` is telling your code that you guarantee it will not be nil, but as you can see, it can with your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the value is being accessed before it's ready. You'll need to unwrap it to be sure it's assigned before use.

try this:

```
guard let safePaid = paid else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing `dict["paid"]` instead of `paid`. If you print `paid`, you'll probably see that it's nil.

Comment: Yeah but paid = dict["paid"] as? Bool

Comment: I don't know what that means. Did you try printing `paid` instead of `dict["paid"]`? That should be the answer to your problem.